# How do I fix the size of multiple ggplot plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I noticed when combining multiple ggplots, where the values in one are much larger than the other, because the y axis ticks are larger in the former (due to being bigger numbers), it makes the plot itself smaller. To illustrate:

```
df <- data.frame('name'=1:30,'v1'=rpois(30, 1),'v2'=rpois(30, 100))
p1 <- ggplot(data=df,aes(x=name,y=v1)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
p2 <- ggplot(data=df,aes(x=name,y=v2)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
combined <- ggarrange(p1, p2, ncol=1, nrow=2)
print(combined)
```

[image: two barcharts produced]

Note that the bottom plot is slightly smaller than the top plot, because the the numbers in the y-ticks are larger. Is there anyway to make it so that the plots themselves are exactly the same size? (That doesn't involve manually changing the tick sizes until the plots look approximately the same). I tried using ggplotGrob(), which was suggested elsewhere, but it didn't seem to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [{patchwork}](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/) library does this nicely by default.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

df <- data.frame('name'=1:30,'v1'=rpois(30, 1),'v2'=rpois(30, 100))
p1 <- ggplot(data=df,aes(x=name,y=v1)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
p2 <- ggplot(data=df,aes(x=name,y=v2)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')

p1/p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Just add `library(egg)`
It seems that you have loaded `library(ggpubr)` that also have a `ggarrange` function:

```
library(egg)

df <- data.frame('name'=1:30,'v1'=rpois(30, 1),'v2'=rpois(30, 100))
p1 <- ggplot(data=df,aes(x=name,y=v1)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
p2 <- ggplot(data=df,aes(x=name,y=v2)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
combined <- ggarrange(p1, p2, ncol=1, nrow=2)
print(combined)
```

[image]